# Primefaces poll continues working after OmniFaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler error page is displayed

Tags: jsf, primefaces, exception, polling, omnifaces

```
<h:form>
    <p:poll
        id="poll"
        interval="5"
        autoStart="true"
        onerror="window.location='http://www.google.com'"
        partialSubmit="true"
        process="@this"
        widgetVar="managedPoll"
        global="true"
    />
</h:form>
```

The "PF('managedPoll').stop();" inside error page do not stop the next call, only the following (second onwards). Then, another exception is thrown(ViewExpiredException).

Comment: Which PF and JSF versions?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem with stopping the poll inside error page. Works just fine for me. Poll stops immediately. Using PrimeFaces 5.0 community version as available [here](http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html).

Comment: @BalusC, I realized that putting a p:panel inside error page generates the error(p:poll continues working). Test it. (PF5, jsf 2.2.7, Tomcat7);

Comment: Still works for me. Is the panel lazy loading? Did you put the script outside the panel? In any case, in the future please immediately post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @BalusC, I made this example: [link](http://pastie.org/private/1xzg5nloegpgveiqgkhw)